# Infinite run after adding osm service in a map content and using the paint method of the StreamingRenderer class

Tags: openstreetmap, geotools

When I add osm service in a mapContent

```
mapContent.addLayer(new AsyncTileLayer(new OSMService("Mapnik", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/")));
```

Then when I use the paint method of StreamingRenderer class, there is an infinite run. More precisely the infinite run occurs in the line 563 of the StreamingRenderer class file with :

```
painterFuture.get();
```

I call paint method to paint what I add to the mapContent, i.e. here the featureLayer and the osm map.

```
MapContent mapContent = new MapContent();
mapContent.addLayer(new AsyncTileLayer(new OSMService("Mapnik", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/")));

CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
ReferencedEnvelope envelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(566516.1128181651, 571832.3519307065, 5275726.889218023, 5281104.067690026, crs);
mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(envelope);

GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
renderer.setMapContent(mapContent);

Rectangle imageBounds;
ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds;
try {
    mapBounds = mapContent.getMaxBounds();
    double heightToWidth = mapBounds.getSpan(1) / mapBounds.getSpan(0);
    imageBounds = new Rectangle(5, 5, 1000, (int) Math.round(1000 * heightToWidth));
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

BufferedImage mapBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageBounds.width, imageBounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D gr = mapBufferedImage.createGraphics();
renderer.paint(gr, imageBounds, mapBounds);
```

Here is the content of the painterFuture object :
state = 0,
callable = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@3533df16[Wrapped task = org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread@15d0849],
outcome = null,
runner = "Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]",
waiters = null

When there is just the featureLayer and not the osm service,
the painterFuture object is marked as **Completed normally** and contains :
state = 2,
callable = null,
outcome = null,
runner = null,
waiters = null.

With this following code I get an image but that doesn't seems to be the good projection.

```
ReferencedEnvelope re = layer.getBounds();
mapContent.addLayer(new AsyncTileLayer(new OSMService("Mapnik", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/")));

CoordinateReferenceSystem source = CRS.decode("EPSG:25832");
CoordinateReferenceSystem target = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(source, target, true);
Envelope targetGeometry = JTS.transform(re, transform);

ReferencedEnvelope envelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(targetGeometry, target);

mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(envelope);
```

Comment: Did you try turning logging to fine or stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @IanTurton, Yes I stepped through with a debugger,
that is how I knew that the problem was in the paint method of the StreamingRenderer class.
Here is the content of the painterFuture object :
state = 0,
callable = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@3533df16[Wrapped task = org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread@15d0849],
outcome = null,
runner = "Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]",
waiters = null

Comment: your example code doesn't work - but gives me an error 
WARNING: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
 at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:333)
 at org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer.createImage(TileLayer.java:168)
 at org.geotools.tile.util.TileLayer.draw(TileLayer.java:85)
 at org.geotools.renderer.lite.CompositingGroup$WrappingDirectLayer.draw(CompositingGroup.java:227)
 at

Comment: @IanTurton, Sorry, I didn't change the variable name "map" to "mapContent" in this example to get the maxBounds.

Comment: Please post a small working example that demonstrates your problem

Comment: @IanTurton, Ok, I edited my post, I think this time this is a small working example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are asking for an area the size of millions of Earths across, so it takes a long time to calculate all the possible (empty) tiles that need to be requested from the OSM server.

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
ReferencedEnvelope envelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(566516.1128181651, 571832.3519307065, 5275726.889218023, 5281104.067690026, crs);
mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(envelope);
```

is the problem, those coordinates are clearly not in EPSG:4326 (which is in degrees and runs from -180,180 and -90,90. I suspect you mean EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator).

Fixing that lead to another problem which was that you were exceeding the `MaxTileLimit` of 128 and also requesting tiles of size 0x0 in the tile layer.

This is because your screen area was 0x0 - so adding the line:

```
mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(imageBounds);
```

made it run with out error.

### Update

Here is the code I used to test.

```
package spike;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.renderer.GTRenderer;
import org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.tile.impl.osm.OSMService;
import org.geotools.tile.util.AsyncTileLayer;
import org.geotools.util.URLs;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException;

public class OSMLayer {

  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, TransformException, FactoryException {

    FileDataStore ds = new ShapefileDataStore(URLs.fileToUrl(new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp")));


    Layer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(), SLD.createSimpleStyle(ds.getSchema()));
    MapContent mapContent = new MapContent();
    mapContent.addLayer(new AsyncTileLayer(new OSMService("Mapnik", "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/")));
    mapContent.addLayer(featureLayer);
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857", true);
    ReferencedEnvelope envelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(566516.1128181651, 571832.3519307065, 5275726.889218023,
        5281104.067690026, crs);
    mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(featureLayer.getBounds().transform(crs, false));

    GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
    renderer.setMapContent(mapContent);

    Rectangle imageBounds;
    ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds;
    try {
      mapBounds = mapContent.getViewport().getBounds();
      double heightToWidth = mapBounds.getSpan(1) / mapBounds.getSpan(0);
      imageBounds = new Rectangle(5, 5, 1000, (int) Math.round(1000 * heightToWidth));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    BufferedImage mapBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageBounds.width, imageBounds.height,
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(imageBounds);
    Graphics2D gr = mapBufferedImage.createGraphics();
    renderer.paint(gr, imageBounds, mapBounds);
    try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("out.png"));
        ImageOutputStream outputImageFile = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {

      ImageIO.write(mapBufferedImage, "png", outputImageFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

With my US States layer (`mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(featureLayer.getBounds().transform(crs, false));` ) it gives this output:

[image]

With your bounding box (`mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(envelope);`)it gives:

[image]

Comment: I tried with 
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857", true);
and
mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(imageBounds);
but this gives the same effect...

Comment: I tried with :
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857", true);
mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(layer.getBounds().transform(crs, false));
But the output says the longitude and latitude are out of their allowed limits.

Comment: Then your layer bounds are wrong but that is a new question